# Using Instant, LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime with Spring Boot and ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jackson, spring-data

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.4 and [Spring Data Jest](https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-data-jest) with ElasticSearch. I was initially using Java Date for some properties with the following annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern ="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
```

This is saved into ElasticSearch as follows:

```
"creationDate": "2019-04-10T14:49:05.672+0000"
```

Now, I am in the process of migrating from Date to LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime. When the data is now saved to ElasticSearch, I get the following attribute saved:

```
"creationDate": {
    "dayOfYear": 123,
    "dayOfWeek": "FRIDAY",
    "month": "MAY",
    "dayOfMonth": 3,
    "year": 2019,
    "monthValue": 5,
    "hour": 11,
    "minute": 54,
    "second": 12,
    "nano": 238000000,
    "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
    }
},
```

What do I need to do to change it so I get the same ElasticSearch data format as before for LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime?

I have tried the following:

1. Customising the object mapper as follows:

   ```
   public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {
       private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

       public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {  
           this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
           objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
           objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
           objectMapper.registerModule(new CustomGeoModule());
           objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
       }

       @Override
       public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
           return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
       }

       @Override
       public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
           return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Adding the following to object mapper:

   ```
   objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
   ```

Any help or pointers where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Never use `LocalDateTime` to represent a moment, as that class purposely lacks any cancer of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` to represent a specific point on the timeline.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, why should LocalDateTime not be used? My example is a field for creationDate.

Comment: Your JSON input is representing a moment, a specific point on the timeline. A **`LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment**. Read the class doc. Read many other postings on the subject here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: FYI, what you refer to as “ElasticSearch data format” is actually standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for textually representing date-time values. These formats are used by default in *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: Your example ISO 8601 string does not match your example JSON. When providing example data, be accurate.

Comment: Could you provide code sample of class (including annotations) you are trying to serialize to JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to get it to work with Spring Boot 2.1.4 and Spring Data Jest. Here is what I did:

1. Example domain object:

   ```
   @Document(indexName = "datetest")
   public class DateTest {

       @Id
       private String id;

       @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
       @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern ="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ", timezone = "UTC")
       private Instant instant = Instant.now();

       @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
       @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern ="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
       private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();

       @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
       @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern ="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
       private LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

       // getters/setters
   }
   ```
2. The ElasticSearch/JEST config:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class ESConfig {

       @Bean
       public EntityMapper getEntityMapper() {
           return new CustomEntityMapper();
       }

       @Bean
       @Primary
       public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate(final JestClient jestClient,
               final ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter,
               final SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext simpleElasticsearchMappingContext, EntityMapper mapper) {
           return new JestElasticsearchTemplate(jestClient, elasticsearchConverter,
                   new DefaultJestResultsMapper(simpleElasticsearchMappingContext, mapper));
       }

       public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

           private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

           public CustomEntityMapper() {
               objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
               objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
               objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
               objectMapper.registerModule(new CustomGeoModule());
               objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
           }

           @Override
           public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
               return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
           }

           @Override
           public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
               return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
           }

       }
   }
   ```
3. The results in ElasticSearch:

   [image: Screenshot of results in ElasticSearch]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `spring-data-jest` uses `DefaultEntityMapper` (part of Spring Data), which creates its own `ObjectMapper` and doesn't use the one provided by Spring boot. This can be seen in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202929/how-to-make-spring-data-elasticsearch-work-with-java-time-localdatetime-for-date).

You're on the right track with your solution by defining your own `EntityMapper`, for example `CustomEntityMapper`. However, `spring-data-jest` wraps this mapper into a class called `DefaultJestResultsMapper`, which is then used by a bean called `JestElasticsearchTemplate`.

So, probably you should do something like this:

```
@Bean
public JestResultsMapper resultMapper(CustomEntityMapper entityMapper) {
    return new DefaultJestResultsMapper(entityMapper);
}

@Bean
public JestElasticSearchTemplate template(JestClient client, JestResultsMapper resultsMapper) {
    return new JestElasticSearchTemplate(client, resultsMapper);
}
```

This should inject your `CustomEntityMapper` into a `JestResultsMapper`, which is in turn injected into `JestElasticSearchTemplate` used by the framework.

Within `CustomEntityMapper` you can either autowire the default `ObjectMapper` (which will automatically add the `JavaTimeModule`) or you can configure one on your own.

Comment: Hurrah! The above part was what I was missing. There were so many answers and different configurations so I stripped it back to a basic Spring Boot 2 test app and got it to work. I'll add my sample class and configuration above. Hope it helps other people, thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29959842/1183296) from version 2 of Spring Boot,it should work out of the box as you want in terms of producing string from java.time objects

If you have

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.4.0
```

as dependency and below line in application.properties

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

So only thing left would be to add timezone notation to default string which won't have it.

If standard formatters won't work for you may always write your own serialiser/deserialiser and attach it like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52733731/1183296)

Comment: That will work to configure the default `ObjectMapper`, but this mapper isn't used by the spring-data-jest framework, so this solution won't work.

Comment: @g00glen00b thanks for claryfing that, I wasn't aware about that. I tried to help with gathering informations from other threads.