# Mapping OffsetDateTime with ElasticsearchRestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm switching from `TransportClient` to `RestHighLevelClient` in my app, which uses `spring-data-elasticsearch`. When I try to save an entity with a field of type `OffsetDateTime`, I get the following exeption:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse field [createdAt] of type [float]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=json_parse_exception, reason=Current token (START_OBJECT) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
 at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@2d7d44ce; line: 1, column: 35]]];] with root cause

org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=json_parse_exception, reason=Current token (START_OBJECT) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
 at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@2d7d44ce; line: 1, column: 35]]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:509)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:420)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:450)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.failureFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:616)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:169)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2050)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2026)
...
```

Here is my Elasticsearch config:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public RestHighLevelClient client() {
    return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(elasticsearchHost, elasticsearchPort)));
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(RestHighLevelClient client) {
    return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client);
}
```

And here is the simplified entity definition:

```
@Data
public class MyEntity {

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

}
```

What should I configure in order to be able to use fields of type `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: This might be able to help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202929/how-to-make-spring-data-elasticsearch-work-with-java-time-localdatetime-for-date

Comment: which versions of Spring, Spring Data Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch do you use?